# How can I find the value for which the function has no solution?

Tags: functions

$$f(x)=4-3\sin x$$ is defined for the domain $$x \in [0,2\pi]$$

I have to find the set of values of k, for which $f(x)=k$ has no solution.
Now I got one, by taking the biggest possible value sin can get, which is 1, so I got $4-3=1$, it is not possible to get a smaller number, so $k<1$ is one solution.
Apparantly, the other one is $k>7$. But how do I get that 7? for $4-3sinx$ to be 7, we need $sinx$ to be negative, which is not possible for the domain. (0-2pi= 0-180 degree). The sin graph doesn't have -1 as a value between 0 and 2pi.

2, How can I sketch this graph without using any program? I know that the y intersect will be 4, but how do I modify the sin graph with the -3? And how to make it accurately in an exam?

Comment: Be careful: $[0,2\pi]$ maps to $[0,360]$, so the range of $\sin x$ is $[-1,1]$.

Comment: Um, 2pi = 360 degrees.  Not 180 degrees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is well-known that over a full period,

$$-1\le\sin x\le1$$ and all values in this range can be reached.

Then

$$-3\le-3\sin x\le3$$

and

$$1\le4-3\sin x\le7.$$

---

Starting from the standard sinusoid, the effect of the factor $3$ is to triple the amplitude (oscillations between $\pm3$ instead of $\pm1$).

The effect of a negative factor such as $-3$, is to reflect around the $x$ axis.

The effect of the added constant $4$ is a vertical shift by four units.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. That approach to solve the inequality is much better than the one I tried.

Comment: The graph is great too, so I should shift the curve by the number, and then multiply the 'size of the wave' (2) by the number infront of sin everytime? Does this apply to cos graphs too?

Comment: Cos x should be reflected around the x-axis, right? The other 2 factors should be the same

Comment: @JohnFire: oops, sorry, the reflection is always around $x$.

Comment: Ahh okay, well I used geogebra to check, and the y axis looked legit too in case of sin. :D Thank you :) So then it's the same for cos graphs in every aspect

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this, you must find the range of $f(x)$. Since $f(x)$ is a sine function, the maximum value will be $4+3=7$ and the minimum value will be $4-3=1$. The only values of $f(x)$ fall between the two, so there is no solution when 
$$7<k$$
or
$$k<1$$
Your error: you said that $4-3=1$ was the maximum and not the minimum. This is not so, as the coefficient of $\sin x$ is negative, not positive, and the maximum of $f(x)$ occurs at the minimum of $\sin x$.

Answer (score 1):

Assume the negation

$$k=4-3\sin (x) $$
and
$$\sin (x)=\frac {4-k}{3} $$
this is impossible if

$$\frac {4-k}{3}>1$$ or
$$\frac {4-k}{3}<-1$$

which give
$4-k>3$ or $4-k <-3$
and finally

$k <1$ or $k>7$.

Comment: Thank you, this is a nice method too

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question directly:

" we need  $\sin x $to be negative, which is not possible for the domain. ($0-2\pi= 0-180$ degree). "

If $0 < 90=\frac {\pi}2 < x < 270 =\frac {3\pi}2<360=2\pi$ then $\sin x $ is negative.

And at $x=\pi =180$ , $\sin x =-1$

Comment: Oh yeah, 2 pi is 360degrees, not 180.. my bad.

Comment: You also didn't note sin x is neg for 90 < x < 270

Comment: isnt it 180-360? sin90 is 1, sin 180 is 0, and sin 270 is -1

Comment: so it can't be negative for 90-180

Comment: Argh.  Good god!  You are right!  I always confuse sin with cos.  Somehow the x value and the altitude get intertwined in my mind.

Comment: Haha, happens :D